# Win 7 - "unidentified network" / "virtualbox-host-only network"

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, virtualbox

I somewhat strangely cannot connect my computer (Win7) to the internet anymore because it is "currently connected" to an "unidentified network".

Network Center says I'm on the "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" - even when starting in secure mode - and I suppose that's why.
Which doesn't mean that it's making sense, mind, for I am NOT running a VM and the "host" is Win7 itself.

My device manager is listing the following network adapters:

-Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection

-Intel(R) Centrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN

-Microsoft Adapter for virtual WIFIs' Miniports

-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter

Disabling VBHO-Adapter will result in "no connections available", even though I can use networks I had previously used on other devices without problems. And just for the record: rebooting doesn't change a thing.

I frankly have no idea what happened - and I didn't have this issue until this morning - but I would greatly appreciate any help in resolving this.

Answer (score 0):

I still have no idea what happened, but it would appear cursing at the darn thing actually worked, for a change. Logged into a different user, hard disabled and enabled the network and for whatever dubious reason, that helped.